# pintrest not populating image tags while pinning image

Tags: jquery, colorbox, pinterest

I cant figure this out. I am using pintrest pinit button to tag images in pintrest. While hitting the pinit button as the description I am only getting the page title. I would like to have the image alt tag to be pre populated as the description. Or I can use the title tag instead. Either way I am getting just the page title as the description for all the images in that page.

Here is my JS

```
$('#colorbox').appendTo('#slideshow');
        $("a[rel^='example']").colorbox({
            open:true,
            close:false, 
            width:480,
            onOpen:function(){  
              $('#colorbox').addClass('cbox-alt');

              // variables used to build pinterest URL
              var baseurl = 'http://www.dnalandscape.com';
              var imgsrc = $(this).children('img').attr('src'); 
              var desc = $(this).children('img').attr('alt');

              $('#cboxContent').append(
                "<div id='pinterest'><a data-pin-config='none' href='//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=" + baseurl + "&description=" + desc + "' data-pin-do='buttonPin'><img src='//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_20.png' alt='Pin it'/></a></div>"
              );        
            },
        });
```

Here is the link to the page where I am doing this.

http://www.dnalandscape.com/projects/southern_CA.html

Comment: On the page you provided, there is no `alt` attribute for the image shown, which seems to be making the description come up as `undefined`... unless there's something I'm missing.

Comment: @lando--I guess I didnt bother to check the obvious. Thanks for pointing that out. Yes it is the problem. Apologies!